# The tense and meaning of 'Would have changed'

Tags: tenses

In an article, a film director talks about her film. "It says something about a woman, about a way of living a life, about life after the war. It was the first thing I had to pour out of myself" She says and then she adds: **"I would have changed nothing about it."**
Does the latter quotation means "I wanted to change nothing about my film"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words were from the film director [Chantal Akerman](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Chantal_Akerman), about her first film *Saute ma ville*, or *Blow up my town* (English).

The fuller quote is

> I sometimes think I should have made it after many other films, at the end of my career. [...] I remember saying to myself, how can I make a better film? But it was also exactly the film I had to make then. It says something about a woman, about a way of living a life, about life after the war. It was the first thing I had to pour out of myself. [...] I would have changed nothing about it.

From fuller context, it seems apparent that she didn't want to ***change the film***, because it *needed to be made*.

Comment: About the question of tense in "I would have changed nothing about it." If she had made it at the end of her career, it might have been technically better and more accomplished, but it was a cathartic work of its time, and on reflection could not have been improved.